# Jquery Check if Something Has Posted $_POST in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I haven't been able to find an answer to this that works. All I want to do is check with Jquery to see if something has been posted in PHP.

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In") {  
    //some code
};
```

And for the Jquery:

```
if (<?php $_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In" ?>) {
        $("#clockin").click(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#clockout").removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    };
```

Comment: That's an odd thing to do. You could check the `$_POST` var in PHP and then conditionally include/omit the jQuery code block as required. The integration with JS code is moot given the client/server side divide.

Comment: do you want to check it on Page Load or every interval ?

Comment: `if (<?php echo ($_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In")?'true':'false'; ?>) {` though you should really be doing this in one language or the other - this is probably a sign you are misunderstanding how http works

Comment: Anytime #clockin is clicked.

Comment: is #clockin your submit button? and is it inside Form ? I assume that its because you are using $_POST on server for it ,so if its small part of page and you don't want to rendered whole page again go For Ajax Form Submission asynchronous way or if you want to reload the whole page use synchronous path i.e send it on HTTP request

Comment: @Steve, this worked. Are there any issues I might run into doing it this way?

Comment: @muninn9 Only that it becomes hard to read, and might lead you to forget that the php code has ran and exited before the javascript is loaded. It would be easier to just set the `disabled` attribute of the element directly via php

Comment: All the help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php if ( isset($_POST['clockin'])) { 
    if ( $_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In") { ?>
        $("#clockin").click(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#clockout").removeAttr('disabled');
        });
<?php } } ?>
```

Make sure you enclose script with `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix Server and Client Code(JS) unless you have no option but you can embed php in html thats advantage of scripting
If you want to check it on Page load if previous page was form submission

Use Flag to check whether clock in is set 
**php**

```
<?php
  $flag=false;
   if ($_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In") {  
        $flag=true;
   }
?>
```

**html**

```
<html>
   <body>
       <form onsubmit="return changeAttr(<?php echo $flag ?>);"> 
           <input type="submit" id="clockin" />
           <input id="clockout" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function changeAttr(flag) {
  //alert(flag);
  var clckin = document.getElementById('clockin');
  var clckout = document.getElementById('clockout');
  if (flag) {
    clckin.disabled = true;
    clckout.disabled = false;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```